# No data are being shown on the data Grid View

Tags: c#, gridview, datagridview

Here's how I'm trying to get data to my `GridView`

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;
BindingSource bi = new BindingSource();
var er = db.DProcesss
           .Select( x => x.Cdate.Year == dt.Year
                         && x.Cdate.Month == dt.Month
                         && x.Cdate.Day == dt.Day)
           .ToList();
    
bi.DataSource = entity.ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = bi;
```

But no data are being displayed. What's wrong with the code I'm using?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example in order to ask a good question.

Comment: look at this line `dataGridView1.DataSource = bi;` i think you used **bi** Instead of **er**